# Is rellax.js unable to specify area?

Tags: javascript

I am using rellax js　on my project.
I want to use rellax js for a specific area, not the whole.
I read the document of rellax js.

I did exactly as written in the document.
But it does not work.
I want the elements to move within the identified area.

Please advise if there are people who know what to do.

> Custom Wrapper By default, the position of parallax elements is
>   determined via the scroll position of the body. Passing in the wrapper
>   property will tell Rellax to watch that element instead.

```
<script>
  //Set wrapper to .custom-element instead of the body
  var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax', {
    wrapper: '.custom-element'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I guess, just from that piece of documentation you've posted, that it's using the _wrappers scroll_ to move the elements. If the wrapper doesn't have scroll, it may not move at all. Maybe you should apply the effect to the wrapper only, but still watch the body's scroll.

Comment: Does that mean that the specified wrapper does not have height? Is that a problem?

Comment: That the wrapper doesn't scroll its contents. I understand that you want the wrapper to be the only part that moves when the page scrolls (not when the wrapper scrolls its own contents). It seems that the effect is only applied to the elements with `rellax` class (or whatever you put there in the constructor). So you should set that class name only to the elements of the page that you want to get animated, and there should be no need to change the wrapper. If you don't want the elements to go outside that area, change the overflow of the parent to hidden.